# Would these upgrades give me a better bike than I could buy with my budget plus the sale of my current bike?

Tags: road-bike, upgrades

Thanks to everyone who commented on my previous post. I’ve narrowed my options down and would really appreciate advice on the more specific ideas I have in mind at this point.

I'm considering making the following upgrades to my 2019 Specialized Allez. I’ve budgeted about $500 (not including LBS install costs). I've listed the current specs first, followed by the set of upgrades. I would appreciate any advice about compatibility issues, alternatives, or costs (or inadvertent downgrades) I may be overlooking.

For context, I need to replace the rear derailleur due to damage and I want to replace the cassette with a narrow-range alternative because it’s pretty much flat everywhere here and I’ve found that I never use the top 2 or 3 largest gears on my current 8-speed 11-32. I don’t think I’ve ever used the 11, either. The other upgrades are for performance and safety.

So, here goes.

**Current specs**

Brifters: R2000 Claris

Front/Rear Derailleur: Claris

Crankset: R7000 105 with 52/36T rings

Cassette: SunRace 8-speed 11-32

Chain: KMC X8 w/ Missing Link™, 8-speed

Brakes: Tektro, alloy, dual-pivot

Wheels: Axis Sport

Tires: Espoir Sport, 60 TPI, wire bead, double BlackBelt protection, 700x25mm

Additional specs about the frame, etc. are listed here: https://99spokes.com/bikes/specialized/2019/allez

The only difference from the specs listed at that link is that the bottom bracket has been swapped for a SM-BBR60 round bracket.

**Upgrades**

Rear Derailleur: Replacement Claris RD, plus a new shifter cable ($32)

Cassette: SRAM PG-850 8-speed 12-23T ($30)

Chain: SRAM PC-870 Chain 8-speed ($18)

Wheels: Campagnolo Calima (cheapest I’ve found is ~$180)

Tires: Continental Grand Prix 5000 (~$105 with tubes)

Brakes: R7000 105 Dual-Pivot Caliper Set ($92)

Total Cost: $457 (on a ~$500 budget)

I'm leaning toward making these upgrades because selling my bike would probably net me at most $500, which would leave me with a budget of about $1k.

Accounting for the above upgrades to my Allez, could I buy a much better *new* (not used) bike at the $1k price point? Or would making these upgrades be the better option? I'm leaning toward upgrading, but please let me know if there are better new bikes at the ~$1k price point that I’m overlooking.

Upgrading to 4700 Tiagra 10-speed would cost about $260 more, which I could save for, but I don’t know that it would be worth it. I’d also appreciate any advice on this point.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the actual question? Please note that this is not a forum for free flowing discussions or shopping advise. Have a look at the [tour].

Comment: For discussion and opinions you may come to chat though: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/214/the-velodrome

Comment: Full answers already cover the most parts, but I'd recommend trying replacing brake pads before replacing the entire brakes. Original Tektro pads aren't that good and rubber degrades over time, so new Kool Stop, Swisstop or even most no-brand pads would be an upgrade.

Comment: And if brakes are still not good, replace cables with quality ones.

Comment: @ojs Thank you for recommending alternatives for brake pads. The Tektro brakes have served well enough and I was vacillating over whether to replace them altogether. I'll probably skip the 105 caliper upgrade and just get new pads. If issues persist, I'll look at replacing cables as mattnz has suggested. Thanks to you both!

Comment: @gschenk Thank you for directing me to the tour and to the chat room. I apologize for not seeking these out sooner. I'm only slowly becoming accustomed to the site and its conventions.

Comment: @startagain If you buy a new bike with a similar spec (Spec Allez Claris) the price would be about £800 ($1000?) & you'd be standing still, same old basic wheels, tyres brakes, etc - tho the new colours are pretty cool. By upgrading what you already have, you uprate key parts and renew all the main wear parts. The Tiagra upgrade at the price you list could make sense as if you were buying a new Allez, the price over the basic Claris model is abit more than that. Tiagra would give you an edge for racing but general commuting is better served by 8sp Claris as cassettes and chains are so cheap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$1K USD new would get you in the range of 9 speed Sora with a low to mid-range aluminum frame, so it wouldn’t be too bad of an option either. In the used market, you could likely get 105 11 speed mechanical on a mid-high end aluminum frame.

Those Campagnolo wheels appear to come with the campy freehub body, so you’ll need to factor in the cost of a conversion to HG for Shimano cassette compatibility.

If you’re happy with the 8 speed setup, go for it. If you want to go to Tiagra, then just buy a new or used bike with the additional budget. Having a shop install an entire groupset will get expensive quick. Speaking of which, how much of this work would you be willing/capable of doing yourself? Your own time and/or LBS expenses need to be factored in too.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. The seller offers an HG free hub version of the wheel set, so I'm at least covered on that point. I'm leaning toward keeping the bike at 8-speed since it's my first road bike and I'm primarily using it for training. I don't anticipate winning any competitive races with it, but I have noticed that the gear jumps on the 11-32 cassette disrupt cadence when I want to shift to accelerate from a tempo pace toward a sprint. Hence the 12-23 cassette. Does that decision seem reasonable, at least?

Comment: I would like to upgrade to a better bike asap, but would you say the cost of the upgrades I have listed would be justified in terms of the improvement to the bike as a training tool? My impression is that gaining two gears and reducing weight by upgrading to Tiagra may not be worth the cost given my novice status. Do you think I might be overlooking some of the benefits of upgrading from Claris to Tiagra for a relatively new cyclist?

Comment: @startagain I have the same cassette as you on my commuter and the jumps are ridiculous. The 12-23 is a good idea. Even if you don't think you'll win, you still want to compete as hard as you can. You never know, and you can certainly improve your field ranking!

Comment: @startagain The new cassette and GP5000s will make the biggest immediate difference.  Maybe start with those - you can resell the cassette later, and keep the GP5000s for the new bike if you do decide to go that route.

Comment: Thank you. I was entertaining doubts about my impression of the 11-32 8-speed. I may not win many races on this bike with a 12-23, but at least I'll have fewer excuses. That means more incentive to keep at it. And I'll probably beat some of my Strava PRs. That's always fun. Thanks for the encouragement there.

Comment: I also have great expectations for the GP5000s from what I've read. I have a little room in my budget to maybe substitute better wheels in place of the campy Calima set. Would you recommend any others or do you think these will serve my present purposes? No worries either way. Thanks once again for your advice!

Comment: @startagain You are very welcome! At this pricepoint, almost all wheels will be the same (save for some really bad value-for money brands). Brand or model doesn’t really matter here, just find the best deal you can with the dimensions you want.

Comment: Great! I'll probably opt for the Calima set then, in part because they're offered with the HG/shimano compatible variant. I'll double-check that they'rw compatible, though. Thanks again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116052/discussion-between-maplepanda-and-startagain).

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think the wheel set will be much of an upgrade. I see them for 141€ in Germany and they are quite heavy at 1826g. They also don’t look like they make up for the weight with better aerodynamics. Edit: Something like the Vision Team 35 Comp SL or Fulcrum Quattro LG would probably be an upgrade, especially since they are more aero which should benefit you on a flat course.

Is it really *that* flat and windless in your area? 52/36T chainrings and the 12–23t cassette only give you a speed range of about 16km/h to 56km/h: https://www.ritzelrechner.de/?GR=DERS&KB=36,52&RZ=12,13,14,15,16,17,19,21,23&UF=2135&TF=90&SL=2.6&UN=KMH&DV=speed

That’s something even pros would only use on a flat course.

Are the existing brakes really that bad? Does the cable glide smoothly? If not, maybe you only need new cables+cable housing (and maybe some good brake pads, at least on the front brake).

You might not need a new chain if your existing one has very little wear.

I’d invest the remaining money into some good bicycling clothes, if you don’t have them already.

Comment: I'm not a pro but I'm still using 12-23 cassette with 52/39 crankset. It gives me speed range from balancing on spot to 70 km/h.

Comment: @ojs: I weigh 66kg, when going uphill on normal normal roads even with a 34 chainring and a 11–32 cassette I regularly have to go above 220W to maintain more than 80rpm cadence.  At least for me that’s too much intensity for an easy training ride. Of course when you live in an area where the highest and steepest ascent is an overpass you might be fine.

Comment: that sounds like an odd set of constraints. There's no shame having cadence below 80 at power level that low. I think in that situation one could also walk the bike up the hill and take really short steps to maintain cadence.

Comment: @ojs: At least I have a hard time doing less than 80 or 75rpm. There is a reason why even pros now often have easier gears (e.g. 38t chainring + 30t cassette) for *racing*, not to mention for training. But it really depends on terrain. I’m in the alps, I love easy gears and can’t imagine totally flat terrain. My after-work cycling route has 600m of elevation gain over the first 19km with lots of long 7% – 10% grade sections.

Comment: I have understood that there is a middle ground between Alps and overpass, and most cyclists' legs don't shut down at 75rpm. It's totally okay to write from your personal perspective and be unable to imagine anything different, but it should be declared right at the beginning of the answer.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the wheelset suggestions. The 1826g Calima set saves me about 260g versus my Axis Sport (they're over 2kg). The Fulcrum and Vision sets you mention weigh 1766g and 1740g, respectively. So, they’d save me another 60-86g versus the Calima set. I’ve found Vision at $280, Fulcrum at $265, Calima at $145 (before ship, etc.). Since the weight advantage over Calima isn’t massive, what sorts of aero advantages do Fulcrum and Vision offer that justify the price? I’m just curious what makes these sets so much more valuable than Calima. I could afford the upgrade if I drop the brakes.

Comment: @Michael Also, it really is that flat in my area. I live in a coastal beach town. Headwinds don't really get over 15mph often, unless a hurricane is coming through. But then I just keep the bike and myself inside. For context, I only ever use my 52T chainring and I still haven't found any use for the 28 or 32T gears on my current cassette. I use the 24 occasionally during recovery, but that's about it. That's why I'm opting for the 12-23.

Comment: @startagain: Oh, then the 12–23 cassette really is fine ;)

Comment: Regarding wheel drag: It’s hard to say, I can’t find data for those particular wheels and wheels perform differently depending on the frame and circumstances (e.g. cross wind). Generally the higher the rim and (to a lesser extend) the fewer the spokes the more aero: https://www.hambini.com/testing-to-find-the-fastest-bicycle-wheels/ (scroll down for nice comparison tables) I can’t find specs of the Axis Sport wheels in particular but I guess they have a shallow 23mm high rim. According to the above article, changing to a 35mm high rim would probably reduce your drag by 5 to 10W at 30km/h.

Comment: And just to point out: Personally I still don’t think the wheels make enough difference to really be worth it. Unless you really want to spend your money. Otherwise I’d rather save the money (you’ll certainly need some for maintenance or repairs in the future) or spend it on clothes, chamois cream, nutrition etc.